# Determine if App is running as a 'clickonce' application

Tags: c#, clickonce

I am in the process of writing a library (c# .net 4.0) for use in a number of applications. One of the requirements is that the library returns slightly different results to calls depending on whether or not the application is deployed and running via clickonce.

I've had a search around but cannot find any way that an assembly can determine if the 'hosting' application is clickonce deployed.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add reference to `System.Deployment`, after that you can use:

```
Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed
```

If you need to pass arguments to application, then use:

```
var args = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData;
```

Comment: The namespaces are a bit confusing. All you need to do is to reference static property [ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.isnetworkdeployed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that is available from System.Deployment assembly.

Comment: Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed worked great for me to detect if my app was running as a ClickOnce app. I needed to call a command line program (WinMergeU.exe) and pass some args to compare two files, and have it work in VS2013 Dev environment as well as in the ClickOnce deployed app.  The location of the WinMergeU.exe varies depending on whether running as ClickOnce or in IDE.

Comment: If `System.Deployment` isn't available on your system (or the target system), you can include it by the **nuget package** `FrameworkExtract.System.Deployment`.

Comment: Note: `Application.ApplicationDeployment` isn't available for .NET Core 3.1 nor for .NET Framework 5. For Framework 6+ it's planned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want the [CurrentDeployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.currentdeployment.aspx).  Note that according to the documentation if you call this from an application that is not a clickonce it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

For the newer .net versions the documentation can be [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/access-clickonce-deployment-properties-dotnet?view=vs-2022).

> Starting in .NET 7 and Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4, you can access
> ClickOnce deployment properties by using an environment variable.

Example from the Microsoft docu:

```
NameValueCollection nameValueTable = new NameValueCollection();
if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClickOnce_IsNetworkDeployed")?.ToLower() == "true")
{
    string value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClickOnce_ActivationUri");
    Uri activationUri = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? null : new Uri(value);
    if (activationUri != null)
    {
        nameValueTable = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(activationUri.Query);
        Console.WriteLine("Query string: " + activationUri.Query);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```